# Rails 3: Migrate DB Schema from SQLite to MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, mongodb

Is there an easy way to migrate DB Schema from SQLite (Development Env) and PostgreSQL (Heroku Production Env) to MongoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"mongoimport" supports import of data through CSV or JSON format. If you can: export your data in one of those formats.

More complex data structure likely require some kind of migration/import script to be written by you.

Comment: I agree, more complex data should be handled manually just to be sure that Mongo gets the data in a way that you can actually use it in your app.

Comment: Actually what i meant was the Schema. I have corrected my question above.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently in the process of setting up a new Rails app that will use mongoDB on the backend.  I think that migrating your schema would depend on which ODM you choose to use.  Personally, I choose [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/) because it seemed to fit the best between Rails and mongo.

As far how to migrate your schema.  I don't have an exact answer for you, but Mongoid seems to really implement the feature of ActiveRecord nicely and uses the same conventions.  I would think this is something that you would just want to do manually.